# Replace only the first CSS class

Tags: plugins, customization, html

I'm trying to replace the "thumb-w" CSS class with "thumb-w1", just the first time.
This is the starting function:

```
function start_modify_html() {
   ob_start();
}
function end_modify_html() {
   $html = ob_get_clean();
   $html = str_replace( 'thumb-w', 'thumb-w 1', $html);
   echo $html;
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'start_modify_html' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'end_modify_html' );
```

I tried entering "1" in the str_replace in this way:

```
$html = str_replace( 'thumb-w', 'thumb-w 1', $html);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a typo but in your question you say "replace the "thumb-w" CSS class with "thumb-w1"

but in your code you have: $html = str_replace( 'thumb-w', 'thumb-w 1', $html);

Should your code instead remove the space and be: str_replace( 'thumb-w', 'thumb-w1', $html);

Comment: It is not a typing problem. It is an example.
I need to add a CSS class to the first element in the page with class "thumb-w".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with thi code:

```
$html = preg_replace('/thumb-w/', 'thumb-w nolazyload', $html, 1)
```

Comment: Probably not the way you want to be doing this though. Better to find where the class is being added from and prevent it from being added than to run `preg_replace` on the entire DOM. Maybe try: `add_filter('body_class','my_class_names'); function my_class_names($classes) { if ( isset($classes['thumb-w']) ) {$classes[]='nolazyload';} return $classes; }`